# Error when building R package with Travis-CI: Package required and available but unsuitable version

Tags: r, travis-ci

The latest version of a package that my package Imports introduced a breaking change (I think it may be a bug and have filed an issue about it). When I specify the specific version of the package needed in my package's DESCRIPTION file, i.e.:

```
Imports:
    packageName (== 0.1)
```

Then the package builds locally fine and passes all tests. However, the package does not pass [the Travis-CI build](https://travis-ci.org/jrosen48/tidyLPA/builds/342802380?utm_source=email&utm_medium=notification); the following error is returned:

```
Package required and available but unsuitable version(packageName)
```

Does this error suggest that the package will not pass CRAN's checks? How can I address it? The source for the package is [here](https://jrosen48.github.io/tidyLPA/).

Comment: Seems you imposed a particular version and methinks you a) neither ensure Travis  CI would find the _exact same version_ nor do you b) have fully considered what version CRAN may have.   Maybe time to relax that constraint?

Comment: I have not done either of those :) regarding a), can you point me in the direction of helping Travis CI to find the right version? regarding b) CRAN has version `0.7-1`, at least here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MplusAutomation/index.html; is there any straight-forward way to install older versions from CRAN?

Comment: Hello Joshua, were you able to fix this issue? I have similar problem where I need `packageName` to be greater than a particular version number. It passes `devtools:check()` locally but it fails on Jenkins.  I also have created the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416679/how-to-update-package-on-jenkins-to-use-the-latest-version if you can help. Thank you.